# does it make sense to disable processor technologies I don't use? (virtualization etc)

Tags: performance-tuning, vt-x

In my server bios I've found such technologies:

- Intel Virtualization Technology
- Intel VT-d

I don't use them as I don't use virtualization. I'm using server for HFT trading and so I want to "win" several microseconds disabling features I don't need. If it makes sense?

Comment: Suggestion: run a CPU-intensive benchmark with those settings on and off, then compare the results to see if there's an improvement.

Comment: Although, this also probably belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 6):

Under my knowledge, that **may** not have performance improvement, I have never experienced a Performance improvement disabling these technologies (under my cases these technologies helped me gain performance many times but sometimes decreasing the performance). You should run a Benchmark with those technologies enabled and disabled, that would help you decide.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, those are things that your CPU has extra hardware for, so that will not help you with performance. You can disable it as a security measure though.

Comment: That's completely opposite. IOMMU/VTd is the security for dma attack... If you disable it, you disable the security.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.
Those technologies are used whenever required.
They don't have any direct impact on CPU performance.

Comment: who talked about cpu performance?

Answer (score 0):

HP provides a comprehensive set of BIOS and tuning parameters for systems intended to be used in low-latency or deterministic environments. I assume HP because you've mentioned ProLiant servers in your other posts here.

Please see:

[Configuring and Tuning HP ProLiant Servers for Low-Latency Applications White Paper](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01804533/c01804533.pdf)

In short, I set my trading application servers to disable C-States, use the highest power profile, disable Turbo Boost, and sometimes, disable processor and memory monitoring. I lower the timeouts for the integrated watchdog timer and leave the Intel Virtualization options enabled (for flexibility).